# Django TypeError tuple object is not callable?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    ##contain all product information

    CONDITION_TYPE = (
        ("New" , "New")
        ("Used" , "Used")
    )

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
condition = models.CharField(max_length=100 , choices=CONDITION_TYPE)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)
created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: it is fixed thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says its a `TypeError` occurring as a result of a missing comma in the tuples.
This

```
    CONDITION_TYPE = (
        ("New" , "New")
        ("Used" , "Used")
    )
```

Should be seprated with a comma

```
    CONDITION_TYPE = (
        ("New" , "New"),
        ("Used" , "Used")
    )
```